# Comparing user input with a list inside the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Thanks for your time.

I've a requirement on SHELL SCRIPT where I've to get the user input and compare it with the list of contents in a text file and see if the input matches with any one of the line in the text file.

Below is the scenario :
cat fruits.txt
apple 
orange 
mango
grapes

Enter the fruit name : gooseberry
That's not in the store!!
Enter the fruit name : apple
Welcome to the world of apple !

Any help would be much appreciated. :(

Comment: Have you tried `grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the file fruitlist.txt where your list of fruits (or whatever) is stored.

Content of fruitlist.txt:

```
red apple
green apple
orange
mango
grapes
```

Note, that after each fruit there is a newline.

The following bash script expects the path to the fruit list file as it's first argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

listFile=$1

if [ -f "$listFile" ]; then
    echo "Type 'q' or 'Q' to exit the script."
    echo "-----------------------------------"
    while true; do
        read -p "Type the fruit name: " fruit
        if [ "$fruit" = "q" ] || [ "$fruit" = "Q" ]; then
            break
        elif [ "$(grep "$fruit" "$listFile")" = "$fruit" ]; then
            echo "The fruit '$fruit' is in the list."
        else
            echo "The fruit '$fruit' is not in the list."
        fi
    done
    echo "-----------------------------------"
else
    echo "No fruit list file specified."
fi

exit 0
```

The statement

```
if [ -f "$listFile" ]; then
```

tests if the fruit list file exists.

The command

```
read -p "Type the fruit name: " fruit
```

reads the fruit name into the variable fruit.

The first if in the endless while loop

```
if [ "$fruit" = "q" ] || [ "$fruit" = "Q" ]; then
    break
```

checks if the user wants to exit the script. The following

```
elif [ "$(grep "$fruit" "$listFile")" = "$fruit" ]; then
    echo "The fruit '$fruit' is in the list."
else
    echo "The fruit '$fruit' is not in the list."
fi
```

checks if the entered fruit can be found in the fruit list file. The grep command alone would find every line which contains the name of the fruit. Lets say you have a fruit with two name parts like 'red apple', 'green apple' etc. The user would enter 'red' and the if would be true. Now the "" = "" in the if statement ensures, that if the user would enter 'red', the statement would not be true and therefore the fruit would not be found in the list.